# How to render svg image in React-Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-native, react-native-navigation

Please try to help me!
I need to render svg image from my folder "project/assest/images/test.svg" on android and ios view.

I have tried :

Solution 1 : `<Image source={imagePath}></Image>`

Solution 2 :

```
import SvgUri from 'react-native-svg-uri';
 <View>
    <SvgUri
      width="200"
      height="200"
      source={{uri:'http://thenewcode.com/assets/images/thumbnails/homer-simpson.svg'}}
    />
  </View>
```

Solution 3 : First i should, convert svg file to png,jpeg then render simple image, but that very weired way on view

Please help, what did i wrong in this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can also try [react-native-svg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-svg) package for SVG

For Example --

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { SvgUri } from 'react-native-svg';

export default () => (
  <SvgUri
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    uri="http://thenewcode.com/assets/images/thumbnails/homer-simpson.svg"
  />
);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this
Happy coding!

Comment: Make sure to check out the docs of the above mentioned package react-native-svg. It offers basically any possible way to use an svg. You can also pass svg as string to one of the components it brings, which I wasn't aware and didn't find through search engines, just in the docs itself.

Answer (score -1):

You can try with this

```
<SvgUri width="200" height="200" source={require('./project/assest/images/test.svg')} />
```

May this will help you

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this too

Comment: If we are using image from url, then we directly assign uri. For image which is inside our folder we have to require in <Image tag also.

Answer (score -2):

here are two ways to use SVG in react-native.
one way is to translate the SVG to JSX use this [site](https://svg2jsx.com/).
the other way is to use a font instead of SVG directly:

1. firstly,  use SVG files to generate font. I use this [site](http://fontello.com/). it is fontello.
2. then I  use react-native-vector-icons to generate icon.
   for more details, you can see its [API](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#custom-fonts)